# restoring raid filesystem

Tags: filesystems, mdadm, partition-table, superblock

I ended up with my 3-disk mdadm array not being able to assemble because each of the disks had corrupted superblocks.

I tried to force reassembling the array using

```
mdadm --create
```

This resulted in the ability to assemble the raid, but now there is no (ext4) filesystem. Other indicators seem to show that the data is still there, but I need to fix the filesystem.

I tried to fix the filesystem by seeing if I can restore the superblock:

```
mkfs.ext4 -n /dev/md0
fsck.ext4 -b <tried_all_of_the_blocks> /dev/md0
```

But I get

```
fsck.ext4: Filesystem has unexpected block size while trying to open /dev/md0
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext4/ext4 filesystem...
```

So I take it that there is no filesystem and therefore, no valid superblocks from which to restore the filesystem.

I have two questions:

**1. Can I safely use mkfs.ext4 on the raid to regenerate the filesystem, without losing the data that appears to still be in the array?**

**2. Can I fix the superblock of the array using a backup from one of the individual disks?**

Obviously, I do not understand many things, so I appreciate your kind response.

Here is the `mdadm --examine` output:

```
    root@server:~# mdadm --examine /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/md0
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : aa70a8ec:192f1719:23bc5df4:1ddac384
           Name : server:0  (local to host server)
  Creation Time : Sat Oct 28 00:21:46 2017
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 4294703103 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
     Array Size : 4294702080 (4095.75 GiB 4397.77 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 4294702080 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=1023 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : bf5a4ff5:e4e3659e:99caca7c:333475f3

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sat Oct 28 05:48:33 2017
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 71521ea5 - correct
         Events : 3358

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : aa70a8ec:192f1719:23bc5df4:1ddac384
           Name : server:0  (local to host server)
  Creation Time : Sat Oct 28 00:21:46 2017
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 4294703103 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
     Array Size : 4294702080 (4095.75 GiB 4397.77 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 4294702080 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=1023 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 91528c6d:77861852:a1a4f630:9d8eb8ab

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sat Oct 28 05:48:33 2017
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 9b0ed7c - correct
         Events : 3358

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : aa70a8ec:192f1719:23bc5df4:1ddac384
           Name : server:0  (local to host server)
  Creation Time : Sat Oct 28 00:21:46 2017
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 4294703103 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
     Array Size : 4294702080 (4095.75 GiB 4397.77 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 4294702080 (2047.87 GiB 2198.89 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=1023 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : bdc61c9f:321a7ca6:2ed914d0:d10b96a4

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sat Oct 28 05:48:33 2017
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 27a0a727 - correct
         Events : 3358

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/md0.
```

This is all on Ubuntu Server 16.04, with `mdadm` version 1.2

Comment: mdraid doesn't protect against silent/filesystem corruption, only against disk failures. This is why you need backups. You might be able to salvage something from your disk using `testdisk` or some similar utility. For anyone to be able to provide more specific advice, you need to provide more details and a specific enough problem to answer.

Comment: Would you all please check my completely revised question and consider reopening it?

Comment: "_Can I safely use mkfs.ext4 on the raid to regenerate the filesystem...?_" NO! If you run `mkfs.ext4` you will overwrite whatever is present and create an empty filesystem. DO NOT DO THIS

Comment: Ubuntu Server 16.04, mdadm 1.2

Comment: First sentence, "_my 3-disk mdadm array not being able to assemble because each of the disks had corrupted superblocks_". Are you talking about the RAID metadata or the filesystem superblock? The RAID metadata looks ok, and on that basis your RAID array should have assembled just fine.

Comment: @roaima - I'm not sure I know the answer

When I originally tried to re-assemble the array using
`mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1/`
it said that there was 
`no recognizable superblock on /dev/sdb1`
`/dev/sdb1 has no superblock`

After this I tried to restore the superblock on sdb, but I gave up after holding "y" down for 10 minutes (I didn't know that there was an unattended mode of the command I had issued).

After that I decided to run `mdadm --create`

Comment: If you're run `mdadm create` and it didn't refuse then you've probably lost all your data :-(

Answer (score 0):

Between the original failure and your recovery efforts, it sounds like your array is pretty well wrecked.  If you're very lucky, `mdadm --create` put the disks back in their original order with the original layout.  In that case, you can point some data-recovery software such as `foremost` at the array and pull some of the files out, or you can send the disks off to a data recovery company and hope they'll do a better job at it than you can.